# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column    period that has values by Quarters(Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) that I want to convert into associated month (see dict). My code below works however wondering why I'm getting this warning.

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
quarter = {"Q1":"Mar","Q2":"Jun","Q3":"Sep","Q4":"Dec"}
df['period'] = df['period'].astype(str).map(quarter)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" is a warning.  SO contains many posts on this subject.

`df.assign` was added in Pandas 0.16 and is a good way to avoid this warning.

```
quarter = {"Q1": "Mar", "Q2": "Jun", "Q3": "Sep", "Q4": "Dec"}
df = pd.DataFrame({'period': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5'], 'qtr': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df
  period  qtr
0     Q1    1
1     Q2    2
2     Q3    3
3     Q4    4
4     Q5    5

df = df.assign(period=[quarter.get(q, q) for q in df.period])

# Unmapped values unchanged.
>>> df
  period  qtr
0    Mar    1
1    Jun    2
2    Sep    3
3    Dec    4
4     Q5    5

df = pd.DataFrame({'period': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5'], 'qtr': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df = df.assign(period=df.period.map(quarter))

# Unmapped values get `NaN`.
>>> df
  period  qtr
0    Mar    1
1    Jun    2
2    Sep    3
3    Dec    4
4    NaN    5
```

> Assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object
>   (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones.
>
> .. versionadded:: 0.16.0

Comment: I think in earlier versions the warning is shown incorrectly sometimes. I am not getting the warning in pandas 0.18.0. But good to learn about assign.

Comment: This answer fits perfectly. Compared to other situations which trigger this error, this one doesn't have a filtering step. This one works well for when you chain multiple operations to create a newly computed column.

Comment: what if I want to add a column in-place? e.g when iterating inside a method over a list of DataFrames, I want the change to apply in-place to the input list. the syntax `df['new_col'] = pd.Series(some_vals)` works as I want, but I still get this warning

Answer (score 1):

You are using a sliced Pandas dataframe.

Your best bet is trying a deep copy of the sliced data instead of the original slice. This will ensure [Chained Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) will not happen

```
df['period'] = df.loc['period'].astype(str).copy().map(quarter)
```