# pandas error using df.astype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeconverter

I'm just trying to convert a column of numeric strings to ints. This is what I'm trying:

```
df.date = df.date.astype(np.int64)
```

But I'm getting the warning:

> /Users/austin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2773:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self[name] = value

Not sure what this means. I also tried:

```
df.date = df.date.apply(int)
```

And I get the same warning as above.

Why doesn't this work and what's the proper way?

Comment: In my opinion this code is perfectly, but seems some problem can be in code before. Can you show more rows?

Comment: hmm that comment helped. all I do before this is read in two .pkl files which I thought were the same format and concat them then try to do this operation. however if I do the operations on each individually then concat it works. Not sure why yet I guess I made a bad assumption about the data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928487/a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe) This question has been asked on SO times and again.

Comment: that's helpful, but I don't see that it explains why there's a warning for my concatenated DF but not for each separately

Comment: Did you pass `copy=False` to `pd.concat()`?

Comment: Hmm no I didn't do that. a bit unclear from the docs, does "If False, do not copy data unnecessarily." Mean don't copy duplicates? Because there shouldn't be any duplicates of the same exact row between by df1 and df2

Comment: df.date = does not work, you need df['date']

Answer (score 1):

`astype` function returns a new array. You need to assign the result:

```
date = date.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = pd.DataFrame(['20.1','19.1','12.3'])
x[0].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```